# How to prove that $x^3=6y^2+2$ has only solution $(2,1)$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

How to prove that [diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation): $x^3=6y^2+2$ has only solution $(2,1)$

Answer (score 1):

This is
$$\left(\frac x2\right)^3=\left(\frac{1+3y\sqrt{-3}}2\right)
\left(\frac{1-3y\sqrt{-3}}2\right).$$
We can use unique factorisation in $R=\Bbb Z[\frac12(1+\sqrt{-3})]$ to write
$$\frac{1+3y\sqrt{-3}}2=\omega^j\alpha^3$$
where $\omega=\frac12(-1+\sqrt{-3})$, $j\in\{0,1,2\}$
and $\alpha\in R$. Then $1=\omega^j\alpha^3+\omega^{-j}\overline{\alpha}^3$
and one can proceed from there.

Comment: Dear @LordSharkthe If you can prove that the prolem, we can prove that the Fermat equation: $x^3+y^3=z^3$ no positive integer solution

Comment: Please can you exaplain how to prove Fermat with $n=3$ from your equation ? :)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried an unfinished approach by elementary conclusions, maybe it helps you. Firstly: $$x^3=6y^2+2$$

So, you can conclude, that $x$ is even because right always even. Put $x=2k, (k\in \mathbb{N})$. Then  $$4k^3=3y^2+1$$

From here we conclude that $y$ is odd. Put $y=2m-1, (m\in \mathbb{N})$, we have:
$$4k^3=12m^2-12m+4$$ $$k^3-1=3m(m-1)$$

As, $k^3-1$ must divide $3$, then $k=3l+1, (l\in \mathbb{N_0})$. Then, we obtain: $$3l(3l^2+3l+1)=m(m-1)$$

In the right side we have products 0f consecutive pairs like: $(0;1), (1;2), (2;3)$ and so on. All divisors of $3l^2+3l+1$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $6$ [see proof here](https://oeis.org/search?q=7%2C%2019%2C%2037%2C%2061%2C%2091%2C%20...&language=english&go=Search). Not including trivial solutions $m=1, l=0$, we proceed further... By above congruence and by that $m(m-1)$ divides $3$, we restrict our consecutive pairs to these: $(6;7), (12;13), (18,19), (24; 25),...=(6j;6j+1), (j\in \mathbb{N})$

And, I left with proving:
$$\frac{l(3l^2+3l+1)}{j(6j+1)}\neq2$$

So, I don't know how proceed further, maybe you or someone can finish this...

Answer (score 0):

Facts about [Mordell equations](https://www.google.lt/search?site=&source=hp&q=mordell+equation&oq=mordell+equation&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1l2j0i22i30k1l2.188.2456.0.2660.19.10.0.0.0.0.242.729.0j2j2.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..15.4.725.0..0j0i131k1j0i10i19k1j0i19k1.a8iYW9EPNg0) can be used.

$x^3=6y^2+2$ is equivalent to

$(6x)^3=(36y)^2+432$.

In this case, we're lucky that $-10000<432<10000$, otherwise another method would be needed, as in [this case I've answered before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2273567/236182).

See http://oeis.org/search?q=mordell&language=english&go=Search

in particular (this link is given inside the link), e.g., http://oeis.org/A081120/b081120.txt

You'll find that $a^3=b^2+432$ has exactly two integer solutions, so indeed $(x,y)=(2,\pm 1)$ are the only integer solutions.

Unfortunately, [this link](http://oeis.org/A001014/a001014.txt) only gives integer solutions $(x,y)$ to $y^2=x^3+k$, where $1\le k\le 10000$, $k\in\mathbb Z$, not when $-10000\le k\le -1$.

Apparently, OEIS claims that there exists only a cached copy, after the original web site tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp was shut down in 2017.